# Malformed input-Unknown service URL provided: rds.ap-southeast-1a.amazonaws.com

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I ran `rds-describe-db-instances` and encountered that error.
I've trying searching for service URL for RDS button nothing found (I've gone through the same thing for EC2 command line tools and it was clear and easy)

`ec2-describe-instances` works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can check in AWS forums.

In this [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=319303&#319303) you can find the following:

The endpoits for RDS are regional and don't include the letter for the AvailablityZone.

Try: http://rds.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com without the 'a'.

Any API where the AvailabilityZone is relevant will include a parameter allowing you to specify ap-southeast-1a.